# Writing a time interval in abbreviated form

Tags: word-usage, abbreviation, time

In English if you had a limited amount of space to write "4 days, 22 hours, 5 minutes" you could shorten it like this, and it would be clear:

> 4d 22h 5m

In German the equivalent would be "4 Tage, 22 Stunden, 5 Minuten".
What is an acceptable way of representing this in shorter form?

I have seen this used; a couple of native speakers confirmed this is common:

> 4T 22H 5M

I believe the "H" comes from the Latin *hora*.
However I've also heard someone complain about this format, saying it should be:

> 4T 22S 5M

Is there a standard, or are both equally understandable and accepted?
Is the capitalisation important too in this case?

Comment: I'd _never_ use "4T 22S 5M", and I haven't seen it yet.

Comment: Ich meine Schreibweisen wie 4d3h6'33" schon gesehen zu haben, aber wo die verbreitet sind (Seefahrt?) kann ich nicht sagen - empfehlen würde ich nur die SI-Notation wie von feela beschrieben.

Comment: @user unknown Die Notation mit ' und " findet man auf Anzeigetafeln im Sport, zuletzt gesehen beim Berlin-Marathon. Wikipedia hierzu: [Diese Schreibweise ist nicht korrekt, da ′ und ″ Zeichen für Winkelminute und Winkelsekunde beim Winkelmaß sind.](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minute)

Comment: Als Zeitintervall habe ich auch `02:57:49` schon gesehen, wobei ich aber nicht weiß, auf die wievielstel Sekunde genau man beim Marathon misst. Ohne Kontext kann man auch schlecht ahnen, ob 1:32 nun 1h32 oder 1min32 sein soll.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would definitely prefer

> 4T 22H 5M

to

> 4T 22S 5M

because "S"/"s" usually means "Sekunden" (seconds).

"H"/"h" is a very common abbreviation for "Stunde" (hour), for example

> km/h (Kilometer pro Stunde)

Answer (score 8):

Ohne eine feste Regel nennen zu können: ich hab oft gesehen, dass viele ihre Notation an die [SI-Einheiten](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationales_Einheitensystem)symbole anlehnen, wobei die Minuten oft als 'm' statt 'min' gekennzeichnet werden.

Also:

```
4d 22h 5m 45s
```

Es ist also auch in Deutschland durchaus üblich, die internationale Notation zu verwenden.

Aber: Das große M bezeichnet den Monat, das große T die Zeitangabe (der Dimension) an sich (wie bei einem Countdown "T minus XX Minuten") und das große S ist das Einheitenzeichen des elektrischen Leitwerts (Siemens).

Comment: Also in einem technischen Umfeld würde man das genau so erwarten und richtig verstehen. Bei der in einer anderen Antwort vorgeschlagenen Abkürzung mit T für Tag würde ich stutzen.

Comment: Technisch ist nicht der richtige Ausdruck - alle Wissenschaftler und international Tätigen sollten die SI-Notation nutzen.

Comment: Sollten Wissenschaftler Größen nicht mit einer Dezimalzahl und einer Einheit ausdrücken? 4d 22h 5m 45s erinnert mich an Pfund, Schilling und Pennies.

Comment: Es hängt natürlich vom Kontext ab. Wenn man vergleichen will, ob die Zahl der Bakterien sich in 37h oder 49h verdoppelt, dann macht eine einheitliche Basis sicher mehr Sinn. Will man etwas anschaulich darstellen, wird man es wohl in Tagen ausdrücken + Stunden.

Comment: @Gigili Why are you editing the time-example as a blockquote? I'm not quoting anyone here. If you like to embed the example in a specific tag, you should use `<code>` (represented in Markdow by backticks or indentation by four spaces or one tab). This is against anything I've ever learned about HTML semantics… (Even better would be the HTML5 [`<samp>`-tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-samp-element), but that isn't allowed on the SE-network.)

Comment: @feela: Black quote is used to separate part of the answer which answered the question directly apart from other explanation an answer includes, not only when you quote someone! it makes the reader to pay more attention to that part. That part of the other answer and the question itself are all in the same format, as you've probably noticed. you can edit your text to its original version whenever you want!

Comment: @feela: I completely agree with Gigili, a blockquote the way to go here. The `<code>` tag should be used for, well, code only. There are not many tags available, and blockquote is the best for formatting example sentences and phrases. (It's not exactly a phrase here, but I don't know how to better name it.)